# setting visible an object in GUI MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

I got an error message that I can't understand. I am coding a graphic interface with matlab.

I have this object :

```
S.original = uicontrol('style','text',...
             'unit','pix',...
             'position',[40 240 165 30],...
             'fonts',16,...
             'backgroundcolor',[1 1 1], ...
             'visible','off',...
             'string', 'original signal');
```

then in a function I call :

```
    set(S.original,'visible','on')  % Set visibility.
```

I have this error message :

> Attempt to reference field of non-structure array.
>
> Error in GUI/calcul (line 141)
>       set([S.original],'visible','on')  % Set visibility
>   Error while evaluating uicontrol Callback

Why I can't set to 'on' the visibility of this object ?

Thank you

Comment: You have probably overwritten `S` somewhere or you have not correctly passed it to the function where you attempt to change the visibility. Please provide a *complete* example that reproduces your issue.

Comment: Thank you for you answer, you lead me to find the problem. Actually I was overwritting S as you said.